# Linux Mint: Changing keyboard settings permanently

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I have an installation of Linux Mint 12 which was initially configured to use a different keyboard country settings. Now I'd like to change permanently the keyboard settings to another country's keyboard. So far I've been able to change it with LxkeyMap, however the changes don't survive a server restart. Is it possible to change them permanently ? 
Thanks!